# "Word" characters from the Unicode Set

Tags: php, html, regex, unicode, utf-8

I was wondering how PCRE detects word characters from whatever language.
I was testing this string:

```
"間違つ"
```

The php file is encoded as UTF-8 and is properly tagged with the Charset=UTF-8 in the Content type tag.

```
<?php

$string="\xE9\x96\x93\xE9\x81\x95\xE3\x81\xA4"; //Bytestream from "間違つ" 
$string=preg_replace('/\w/','\w',$string);
echo $string;
echo "<br>";


$byte="\xE9"; //I've tried with each byte separately to find word characters
if(preg_match('/\w/',$byte)){
    echo "$byte is a word";
    }
else{ 
    echo "$byte is not a word";
    }
?>
```

`"\xE9" "\xE9" "\xE3"` from all the bytes, are words.

It display:

[image: Displayed]

I know why the  symbols appear.
The Decoder use the Unicode replacement character, code point FFFD,
as the decoding of an invalid UTF-8 sequence rather than stop processing the text.
There are invalid sequences since one "word character" is replaced by the replacement `'\w'`
and then it broke the "byte secuence" to show.

So the questions are:

**why those characters are matched like words if they aren't valid UTF-8 sequences?**

**How to know wich characters are really word characters of all the Unicode Set?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [`u`-Flag](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) otherwise it is interpreted as a ISO-8859-1 string.

The following script shows which chars `\w` match without the `u`-Flag:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$i = 255;
while($i--)
{
    preg_match('/\w/S', chr($i), $m);
    printf("%' 1s \x%s\n", $m[ 0 ], strtoupper(bin2hex($m[ 0 ])));
}
```

Only [a-zA-Z] are matched by `\w` if `u`-Flag is set:

```
// added 'A' at the beginning and 'B' at the end
preg_match_all('/\w/u', "A\xE9\x96\x93\xE9\x81\x95\xE3\x81\xA4B", $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Attention**: If the `u`-Flag is present preg_* will silently fail to parse the string if it contains non-unicode-chars (e.g. \x80-\xFF).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your regular expression engine is interpreting your stream of bytes as if they were encoded in [ISO Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (which they are not). In ISO Latin-1,

- `E3` is LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE
- `E9` is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE

which are "word" characters, but

- `A4` is CURRENCY SIGN
- `81`, `93`, `95`, and `96` are [C1 control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)

which are not word characters.

You can set the `/u` modifier on the regular expression to request it to work with UTF-8 rather than Latin-1. See the [PHP manual on pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).